# Is it possible to crop multiple images using react-easy-crop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am able to crop one single image using react-easy-crop. However i need to upload multiple images and crop each of those (multiple image crop). Is it possible to achieve the same using react-easy-crop?

Any help shall be greatly appreciated.

Reference Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-easy-crop

Thanks